# Use the URL parameter by variable in HTML with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the same problem as yesterday: i need to use the parameter from URL in the HTML page via AngularJS. What is my mistake?

I need to show and use the parameter like:

```
https://url.com/index.html?user
```

I need to get this "user", but now it does not work, there are no errors now, there is nothing, actually, just an empty h1 with only @. :(

```
<div class="container" id="body-container" ng-controller="myController as myApp">
  <h1 id="header-username">@{{myApp.user}}</h1>
</div>
```

Should I do something else?

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $location) {
        this.user = $location.search();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour for $location service is to work in [hashbang mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-). In this mode, search() method returns the params present after ? only if # is present in the url.

```
http://url.com/index.html#/?user
```

Since your url does not have a #, search() does not return anything.

You could instead try using the [HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode), which does not require # to be present in the url. In this case search() returns {"user": true}.

```
http://url.com/index.html/?user
```

To use HTML5 mode, configure your $locationProvider as below

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
  });
});
```

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nlFRRPhBveeBUMSkwW0V?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angularJS 1.* (I'm not sure if it's the same way with angular2), you can use a $routeProvider and then a $routeParams to get the values from your url.

Check this website to have a good exemple: http://heycodetech.com/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angularjs/

If you want to use the service $location, your problem might be due to the fact that you haven't bind "user". Try something like that:

```
https://url.com/index.html?user='toto'

.controller(‘myController’, function ($scope,$location) {
$outputJson = $location.search(); // will get all parameter of your URL in json format
var param1 = $location.search().user; // will get the value bond to "user"
});
```